# How to convert string ('"12,488"') to float in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have csv file where the raw data and data in dataframe look like that:

```
2013-01-15 07:55:51.537174600+00:00,"37,310112",54
2013-01-15 07:55:52.707176700+00:00,"37,299696",54
2013-01-15 07:55:58.167186300+00:00,"37,310112",54

datetime                               value  IDName 
    2013-01-31 05:00:21.573676100   37,34136      54
    2013-01-31 05:00:22.150877100  37,351776      54
    2013-01-31 05:00:52.945331200   37,34136      54
```

I want to read them do dataframe and do some calculations on values. I tried already:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, parse_dates=True, index_col='datetime', low_memory=False, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

df['value'].astype(float)
```

When I wanted to replace ',' with '.', I used code:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0].replace(',', '.'))
```

However it gave me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

But it gives:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '37,310112'
```

I am confused a bit. Does anyone know how to convert values in column 'value' to floar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameter `decimal`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, 
                 parse_dates=True, 
                 index_col='datetime', 
                 low_memory=False,
                 decimal=',', 
                 quotechar='"')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    df['value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: float(str(x).replace(',', '.')))
```

Answer (score -1):

df['Value'].apply(lambda x:float(x))

Comment: u make sure whether you want to convert or convert and replace both?

Comment: Same error like previous:       ValueError: could not convert string to float: '37,34136'